# Redirect to home page after login using "login with facebook" :Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using "login with facebook" in my application. I want to redirect to home page after hitting the "Login with facebook" button. I dont know how to implement it...

Code is,

```
    <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'APP ID', // App ID
        channelUrl : 'http://www.***.com/', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "js/all.js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
     }(document));
  </script>


<div id="fb-root"></div>
   <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Facebook Event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(){
    window.location = 'index.html';
});
```

new code:

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'APP ID', // App ID
    channelUrl : 'http://www.***.com/', // Channel File
    status     : true, // check login status
    cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(){
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
});

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "js/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
 }(document));
</script>
```

change `index.html` with your homepage url.

if you want to add `logout` too:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(){
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much...but i have an error "Cannot set property 'src' of null ". Why is this error?

Comment: change your login button to `<fb:login-button perms="email,publish_stream" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="window.location = '/index.html"></fb:login-button>`, put your perms there

Comment: try with `window.location.href = 'index.html';`

Answer (score 0):

change your login button to

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,publish_stream" autologoutlink="window.location.href='index.html';"></fb:login-button>
```

Change index.html to your homepage url